# Script won't print output

Tags: python, list

This code simulates an elevator on floor 5, and people comes inside it and choose the destined floor. The code works fine, however when I ask the user for input it won't print out the output.

Like here,

```
class Elevator:
    def __init__(self,initial= 5,floors=35,speed=10):
        self.__initial_value = initial
        self.__current_value = initial
        self.__number_floors = floors
        self.__speed = speed
    def set_requests(self,floor_requests):
        print("="*20 , 'New Request', "="*20)
        error, valid = self.check_requests(floor_requests)
        if len(error) > 0:
            print("Wrong in the series of floor requests: ", error)
        if len(valid) != 0:
            self.__requests = valid
            self.movement()
        print()
    def movement(self):
        self.__requests.sort()
        print('valid requests : ', self.__requests)
        print('Starting ...\n')
        for floor in self.__requests:
            if floor != self.__current_value:
                print("Current floor of the elevator: ", str(self.__current_value))
                print("next destination of the elevator: ", str(floor))
                step = abs(self.__current_value - floor)
                print("the floors left to arrive at the destination: ", str(step))
                print("time left to arrive at the destination: ", str(step*self.__speed) ,'second')
            print("Exit the client on the floor: ",floor)
            self.__current_value = floor
    def check_requests(self,requests):
        error = []
        valid_requests = []
        for request in requests:
            if 0 > request or request > self.__number_floors-1:
                error.append(request)
            else:
                valid_requests.append(request)
        return error,valid_requests



e = Elevator()
e.set_requests = list()
clients = input("Enter the number of clients: ")
for i in range(int(clients)):
    n = input("destinations: ")
    e.set_requests.append(int(n))
```

But when I do set some examples it works fine:

```
class Elevator:
    def __init__(self,initial= 5,floors=35,speed=10):
        self.__initial_value = initial
        self.__current_value = initial
        self.__number_floors = floors
        self.__speed = speed
    def set_requests(self,floor_requests):
        print("="*20 , 'New Request', "="*20)
        error, valid = self.check_requests(floor_requests)
        if len(error) > 0:
            print("Wrong in the series of floor requests: ", error)
        if len(valid) != 0:
            self.__requests = valid
            self.movement()
        print()
    def movement(self):
        self.__requests.sort()
        print('valid requests : ', self.__requests)
        print('Starting ...\n')
        for floor in self.__requests:
            if floor != self.__current_value:
                print("Current floor of the elevator: ", str(self.__current_value))
                print("next destination of the elevator: ", str(floor))
                step = abs(self.__current_value - floor)
                print("the floors left to arrive at the destination: ", str(step))
                print("time left to arrive at the destination: ", str(step*self.__speed) ,'second')
            print("Exit the client on the floor: ",floor)
            self.__current_value = floor
    def check_requests(self,requests):
        error = []
        valid_requests = []
        for request in requests:
            if 0 > request or request > self.__number_floors-1:
                error.append(request)
            else:
                valid_requests.append(request)
        return error,valid_requests



e = Elevator()
e.set_requests([25])
e.set_requests([60])
e.set_requests([17])
```

Kind of stuck on what I am supposed to do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should explain where in your code you are getting the problem. Your code is too long to go through each line and find out first which line/syntax could or could not be giving this error/unexpected output

Comment: `e.set_requests.append(int(n))`  <-- shouldn't this also be `e.set_requests(int(n))`? It's a method of your class, not a list.

Comment: Why do you have so much duplicate code in your question? Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `setter` you just missing the `getter` just add a `get_request` function to your class!

That should do the trick!

By the way you are using `print` wail you should be using `return` and print the results...